# insert trigger ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to create an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER ON Certificare that will update the "salariu" value for that specific person,identified by "idan" with the old value + 100.. I did write the follow trigger and when I try to insert into Certificare it says the following: 04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"

Here are the 2 tables and the trigger :

```
CREATE TABLE Angajati(
    idan INT PRIMARY KEY,
    numean VARCHAR(30),
    salariu INT
    );
CREATE TABLE Certificare(
    idan INT,
    idav INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(idan,idav),
    FOREIGN KEY (idan) REFERENCES Angajati(idan),
    FOREIGN KEY (idav) REFERENCES Aeronave(idav)
    );
CREATE TRIGGER trigNou
    AFTER INSERT ON Certificare
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Angajati
        SET salariu=salariu+100
        WHERE new.idan IN (SELECT idan FROM Angajati);
    END;
```

PS: I'm working in SQL Developer

Answer (score 1):

I would expect something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigNou AFTER INSERT ON Certificare
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Angajati
        SET salariu = salariu+100
    WHERE :new.idan = Angajati.idan;
END;
```

Comment: it says the following :ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Comment: @RacoltaTudor . . . Yes, it needs to be a row-level trigger.

Comment: Isn't it a row-level? The one you provided

Comment: I still get the same error as the one i posted when I do an insert into Certificare